# Winforms MessageBox stucks the main thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, client-server, messagebox

I have a problem with messagebox on winforms.
It seems that when the message box is shown the main thread is stuck and this causes other errors in the system.

There are 2 system, one client and one server. The client has sevral threads that updates the GUI and listen to events from other systems, when the message box is shown these threads can't access the GUI because the messagebox uses the main thread, and it causes errors.

Is there a way to have the message box not to use the main thread ?

Comment: `and this causes other errors in the system.` What are they ? This appears to be [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). so better you can say what problem you're trying to solve

Comment: You CAN, but you really shouldn't. What are the *actual* problems you are facing?

Comment: There are 2 system, one client and one server. The client sends a keep alive event to the server every x seconds, and if that event is not sent an error is written to the log. When the message box is shown, the keep alive event is not sent and errors starts to show on the log every 5 seconds...

Answer (score 1):

You have to reverse your thinking. It's not `MessageBox` that should not be using the main thread, **it really is your keep-alive request that shouldn't**. `MessageBox` will not be the only thing that may potentially prevent the request to be sent: any modal form may end up causing the exact same issue.

The real solution here would be that you change your application's design so that it sends your request in a looping background thread rather than the main UI's, using `Thread.Sleep` between calls to keep your requests at reasonably timed intervals. This will keep on rolling regardless of any calls to `MessageBox.Show()`.

Should you need to alter the UI from that thread in any way, you would only have to use [invocation methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/11/01/calling-delegates-using-begininvoke-invoke-dynamicinvoke-and-delegate.aspx).

Comment: After talking about it with a colleague at work it seems that there are a lot of other threads working in the background. So the problem is still the messagebox...

Comment: @LiranFridman I'm afraid it's unclear how your other threads prevents you from applying the suggested solution. I think always calling `MessageBox`  from another thread is a huge conceptual mistake. Even if it does solve your immediate problem, it's a wide-open door to whole new challenges. Multiple `MessageBox.Show()` calls could be performed in differents threads, getting dialog user input back to the main thread will be harder, etc... I believe you're going to create more problems than you solve. Of course it's your call to make, but I can't encourage you enough not doing that.